# How to use wp_signon() to login using data other than users table in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using one separate table called members to to keep sign up information. I am storing password using wp_hash_password($password).

But when I want login by using wp_signon() then it send 0 as response. I checked wp-includes/user.php to find the details about the wp_signon() and found it is using user_login and user_password as table column name there.

In my members table I have member_username and member_password.

How can I make this workable using members table?

FYI, I am using wp_users table to login into dashboard but for user end I am using wp_members to store all members information.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot reliably make the WordPress Core work without actual users mirrored in the `wp_users` table. You can augment authentication, but a lot of WordPress will still require the `wp_users` (and `wp_usermeta`) table for things like sessions, authorization (permissions), etc. If you do want to offload some of the metadata into your custom table it's fine, but don't mix core logic and business logic like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom table `wp_members` to store user information and you want to use `wp_signon()` with it, you'll need to do some customization because wp_signon() is designed to work with the default `wp_users` table.

```
// Add this code to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin

add_filter('authenticate', 'custom_authenticate', 10, 3);

function custom_authenticate($user, $username, $password) {
    $member = get_member_by_username($username);

    if (!$member) {
        // Member not found
        return new WP_Error('invalid_username', __('Invalid username'));
    }

    if (wp_check_password($password, $member->member_password)) {
        // Password is correct
        return new WP_User($member->ID);
    } else {
        // Password is incorrect
        return new WP_Error('incorrect_password', __('Incorrect password'));
    }
}

function get_member_by_username($username) {
    // Implement a function to retrieve member details by username from your custom table
    // Example: $member = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_members WHERE member_username = %s", $username));

    // Return the member object
    // Example: return $member;
}
```

In the custom_authenticate function, replace `get_member_by_username` with your own function that fetches member details from your custom table.

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(site_url('wp-login.php', 'login_post')); ?>" method="post">
    <!-- Your login form fields -->
</form>
```

custom redirect logic after login, you may need to handle that separately after successful login using `wp_signon()`

```
$creds = array(
    'user_login'    => $username,
    'user_password' => $password,
    'remember'      => true,
);

$user = wp_signon($creds, false);

if (is_wp_error($user)) {
    // Handle login error
    echo $user->get_error_message();
} else {
    // Redirect logic here
    wp_redirect(home_url('/dashboard/'));
    exit();
}
```